# Displaying website when not logged in, and displaying app when logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, web

I have a website and a Rails app.

When a user goes to the website, I want to check if they are logged in or not.
If they are, I want to send them to the Rails application. If they are not logged in I want to send them to the website.

pivotaltracker.com has this type of behavior.

What's the best way to go about this? I figure the Rails app needs to do the log in check so it seems the user should always be sent there first and redirect to the website if not logged in?

But it seems like more often than not the result will be to display the website, so it seems like this adds an extra step, and slows things down for the majority of users. But I'm not sure how else to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the app session cookie in the web server layer of the web site, send them to the app if they have it, continue to the web site if not.

Of course, the app will implement an actual check to find logged-in users and redirect to web site if anything smells funny.

Yes, it's more complex.

Or, stop trying to optimise things before you measure them. "It seems" implies you haven't checked the numbers for what happens more often. (That came off snarkier than intended. I'm trying to remind you about "premature optimisation", not trying to yell at you about it.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using devise, you could:

```
Dashboard::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users    
  authenticated :user do
    resources :stuffs
    root to: "home#dashboard"
  end

  root to: "home#website"
end
```

This will show users the Dashboard if logged in, and the "website" if not. You could then show the website, or redirect to the site.

Comment: In the case of the website being in Wordpress, what would home#website do, redirect?